# Use scroll wheel to scroll down VBA combobox in Excel, lock Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I currently have a sheet in Excel with two Active X control comboboxes on it. These comboboxes are to be typed in, and a dropdown appears populated by strings from another sheet for each box. Is there a way I can program the comboboxes to allow scrolling down through the items in it via a scrollwheel on a mouse? When using the scrollwheel, even when the dropdown is open, the entire sheet scrolls down. I want to have the sheet locked so it can never be scrolled down.

Please let me know if there is a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On your sheet you can restrict the Scroll area to whatever range best suits your need using the following placed under the `Worksheet_Activate` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Me.ScrollArea = YourViewableRange
End Sub
```

Where `YourViewableRange` represents the area that you want to keep on screen. Regards,

Comment: Hi @nybayly , this is not working. I entered the code with Me changed to my sheet name, Tool.ScrollArea = "A1:I18." I then changed the scrolol area in the properties window or the sheet to this range. It will work, until I close and reopen the sheet after saving, and then my range specified inside the project window is gone.

Comment: Where did you place the code? Make sure that you are not placing it in a module but on the Workbook or Sheet Code Modules (in VBA editor double click on your sheets name or on "ThisWorkbook"). When you say "the range specified inside the project window is gone" that sounds to me like your inputting your code on the "Immediate Window" which is only a terminal and only runs code once. Can you confirm?

Comment: The code is on the Tool sheet module under where I declare some variables and before the code for my first combobox. What I mean by disappearing is in the properties window (F4), where options include ScrollArea, StandardWidth, Visible, etc for the sheet itself.